# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

файл increase.js выглядит следующим образом:

```
define('increase', function () {
    return {
        calcProf: function increase (salary, blockNumber){
            salary = salary * (1 + parseFloat($("#list1" + blockNumber + " option:selected").html()));
            getIncrease2(salary, blockNumber);
        }
    };
});
```

при попытке подключить этот модуль на консоль выводится ошибка из заголовка.

Подключение: `var increase = require('increase');`

В чем может быть проблема? сам requirejs скачан и занесен в текущую директорию

Comment: а что за среда выполнения? браузер или локально?
Может просто надо сделать так `var increase = require('./increase.js');`

Answer (score 3):

В неправильном порядке подключения скриптов. Подключай require.js раньше остальных.